# Найти однофамильцев и вывести их информацию

Tags: c

Нужно найти однофамильцев, и вывести их информацию

Не могу понять где ошибка

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

main(){
int i,n,j;
char h;
struct pupil
    {
     char name[20],surname[20],addres[20];
    }persons[20];
printf("Enter amount of students: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
scanf("%c",&h);
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
printf("Student's[%d] name ",i+1);
gets(persons[i].name);
printf("Student's[%d] surname ",i+1);
gets(persons[i].surname);
printf("Student's[%d] addres ",i+1);
gets(persons[i].addres);
}
 for (i=0; i<=n; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++)
     if (strcmp(persons[i].surname, persons[j].surname) == 0)
        printf("%s %s %s %s - %s %s %s %s\n",persons[i].name, persons[i].surname, persons[i].addres,
                                             persons[j].name, persons[j].surname, persons[j].addres);
system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Да, где ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка, например, в количестве `%s` в строке формата.

Comment: Боже, стыдно за такие ошибки, спасибо